File upload works from Swagger, but fails in REST API client , says 413 Request Entity Too Large
My .net core rest api with IIS server setup is able to upload files through the Swagger UI, but it fails when I try to upload from REST API client (Postman or Insomnia) saying "413 Request Entity Too Large".
I am able to upload large files through Swagger, but all files even less than 100 kb fail to upload through REST clients.
My curl from Swagger UI after file upload as follows:
curl -X 'POST' 'https://example.com/api/FileUpload/UploadFile' \
     -H 'accept: */*' \
     -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
     -F 'file=@FiletoUpload.pdf;type=application/pdf'


are you using a framework? which backend?

.net core with IIS server

IIS has a limit for the size of the files users can upload to an application. If the file size exceeds the limit, the application will throw “Error in HTTP request, received HTTP status 413 (Request Entity Too Large)” error.
The default file upload size is 49 KB (49152 bytes).
I suggest you could follow below steps to modify it and then it will work well.
Steps to change the value of this parameter:

Open IIS Manager
Select the site
Double click “Configuration Editor”
Select system.webServer and then serverRuntime
Modify the uploadReadAheadSize value
Click “Apply”

Result:

